# Conditional Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that uses UUIDs as primary keys. New rows are inserted like this

```
INSERT INTO a ( id, ... ) VALUES ( uuid_generate_v4(), ...)
```

Now I actually only want to generate the UUID when no ID is provided in the insert (either `NULL` or an empty string)

Is it possible to write something like this?

```
INSERT INTO a ( id, ... ) VALUES ( $1 || uuid_generate_v4(), ...)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the `isnull()` function, but I see that Postgres does not have it; so use `coalesce()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [coalesce() function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) will use the first non-null. If $1 is null, coalesce() will use uuid_generate_v4(). Otherwise, it will try to use $1.

```
insert into a (id, ... ) values 
(coalesce($1, uuid_generate_v4()), ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the IF function, available in some RDBMS.

```
IF( $1 = NULL, $1, uuid_generate_v4())
```

`$1` being a placeholder.

Also you could set a trigger, if you like them, but mostly they are frowned upon.

And also there are `IFNULL( $1, uuid_generate_v4() )`.

Update: I'm quite surprised that PostgreSQL doesn't suport `IF` which I considered standard.

So as mentioned in other answers, `COALESCE( $1, uuid_generate_v4() )` is probably the best option.

Comment: Most? Does any dbms support an IF() function besides MySQL and MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

You  can alter the table or create the table with a default value for the column.

```
CREATE TABLE thing (
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  updated timestamp DEFAULT now()
);
```

Comment: I'd have to alter the prepared statement for that, so it's not an option.

Comment: This is exactly what default values are useful for.  They guarantee that a column will never have a null value.  The insert statement becomes  INSERT INTO a (  ... ) VALUES ( ... )

Comment: Yes I know, unfortunately in my case I can't alter the schema, so that's that. That's why I asked for checking by function/op.